# In Java why does Arrays.copyOf source code sometimes use reflection?

Tags: java

I'm having trouble understanding this bit of code in java.util.Arrays in openjdk.  I'm curious why this code uses reflection (Array.newInstance) and why it checks to see if the types are the same?  Why can't it just do T[] copy = (T[]) new Object[newLength] even if the type T and U differ?

```
public static <T,U> T[] copyOf(U[] original, int newLength, Class<? extends T[]> newType) {
    T[] copy = ((Object)newType == (Object)Object[].class)
        ? (T[]) new Object[newLength]
        : (T[]) Array.newInstance(newType.getComponentType(), newLength);
    System.arraycopy(original, 0, copy, 0,
                     Math.min(original.length, newLength));
    return copy;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think that `Array.newInstance` is reflection?  AIUI it's just a "normal" method to construct an array of a parameterised class.

Comment: @Andrzej Well the class is part of the `java.lang.reflect` package, which I think makes for a pretty good argument why he assumed reflection. It's actually a native method - maybe some JVM intrinsics at work.

Comment: @Voo Touché, I never noticed its package before (darned IDEs with auto-import making everything easy... :)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *can* - but then you'd end up with an `Object[]` even if you'd asked for a `String[]`. So this *should* fail:

```
String[] strings = Arrays.copyOf(existingArray, 10, String[].class);
Object[] objects = strings;
objects = new Object();
```

... but it *wouldn't* if `Array.copyOf` always actually returned an `Object[]`.

Comment: typo: you should be assigning into some index of `objects` in the last line, e.g. `objects[0] = new Object();`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot instantiate an Array from a generic type like this `new T[newLength]`. So all you can do is `new Object[newLength]`. But Arrays do store information about the item type in order to be able to throw ArrayStoreException, which would be lost in this case.

Comment: Even `new T[ ]` wouldn't match the spec.